Failed to load chart file
I am getting below error while performing a helm push in my github actions workflow. Could any one please helm me out?
    - name: Copy Helm Chart to S3 Prod Helm Repo
      run: |
        helm repo add ${{ env.HELM_PROD_REPO }} ${{ env.HELM_PROD_REPO_URL }}/${{ env.HELM_PROD_REPO}}
        helm s3 push --force ${{ env.HELM_PACKAGE_NAME }}-${{ inputs.PREPROD_VERSION }}.tgz ${{ env.HELM_PROD_REPO }}


Error: failed to load chart file: cannot load a directory
"test" has been added to your repositories
Error: plugin "s3" exited with error

Tried below command but still getting error
helm s3 push --force ./${{ env.HELM_PACKAGE_NAME }}-${{ inputs.PREPROD_VERSION }}.tgz ${{ env.HELM_PROD_REPO }}


you need to install helm s3 plugin in your workflow. Please add below
     - name: Install Helm S3 plugin
        run: helm plugin install https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3.git

